# How to retrieve the user that did the last modification in the site

Tags: sharepoint

I must retrieve the name of the user that did the last modification in a given web, using a Power Shell script.

I know that retrieving the last item modification date is straightforward, but how to retrieve the user that did such modification?

Retrieving the last modified item in the web would be fine too, since I would then pick the value of the "Modified By" field.

Comment: Last change to a site configuration, a list item, a library file?

Comment: The web has the property `LastItemModifiedDate`. What I would need is the user that triggered the change in that date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... just to confirm... You want to check all the items in all the lists and libs in some web and get the last modified item from every list and get the user that modified it, correct? :)

if that is the case this kind of PS script should do the trick

```
    if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
    {
        Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
    }

    try
    {
        $siteUrl="[URL]";
        $web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl;

        $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
        $spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
        $spQuery.Query = ""
        $spQuery.RowLimit = 1;

        $lastDate = $null;
        $lastUser = $null;

        foreach($list in $web.Lists)
        {
            Write-Host 'checking list -' $list.Title;
            $items = $list.GetItems($spQuery);
            if($items.Count -gt 0)
            {
               if($lastDate -eq $null)
               {
                    $lastDate = $items[0]['Modified'];
                    $lastUser = $items[0]['Editor'];
               }
               else
               {
                    if((get-date $items[0]['Modified']) -gt (get-date $lastDate))
                    {
                        $lastDate = $items[0]['Modified'];
                        $lastUser = $items[0]['Editor'];
                    }
               }
            }
        }

        Write-Host 'last user that modfied some item in this web was - '$lastUser ' - ' $lastDate;
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message; 
    }
```

I hope it helps :).

Comment: Indeed that is a solution, thank you. I really hoped there was a handy property that spared me to iterate over all the lists :-) However, your solution doesn't iterate over all the items, so it shouldn't take that long even with a couple of hundreds of webs. How about I ordered by `Modified` descending and also set the `RowLimit` to 1, just as you did; would that work too? Cheers

Comment: hmm... I am not sure If I understood this correctly but if You have couple of hundreds of webs You  can first do a foreach to check in every web the LastItemModifiedDate property and pick the web that has the latest change. After that You may use something very similar to the script I wrote to get the latest modified item(file) and user from this item.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the web object's `LastItemModifiedDate` property to the property with the same name on each list on the site. There should only be one list with the identical `LastItemModifiedDate`.

```
$list = $web.lists | where-object {$_.LastItemModifiedDate -eq $web.LastItemModifiedDate }
```

You can then just query for the most recently modified item in that list and see who edited it.

```
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>"
$query.RowLimit = 1
$items = $list.GetItems($query)
$item = $items[0]
```

A complete script might look something like this (replacing `$webUrl` with the desired web URL):

```
$web = get-spweb $webUrl
$list = $web.lists | where-object {$_.LastItemModifiedDate -eq $web.LastItemModifiedDate }
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>"
$query.RowLimit = 1
$items = $list.GetItems($query)
$item = $items[0]
write-host "$($web.AllUsers.GetById([int32]$item["Editor"].split(";#")[0]).DisplayName) modified item with ID $($item.ID) in $($list.Title) on $($item["Modified"])"
$web.dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an improved and tested version:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$webLastItemModifiedDate = $web.LastItemModifiedDate
$list = $web.lists | where-object {$_.LastItemModifiedDate -eq $webLastItemModifiedDate }    
$formattedLastItemModifiedDate = $webLastItemModifiedDate.toString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + $formattedLastItemModifiedDate + "</Value></Eq></Where>"
$query.RowLimit = 1
$items = $list.GetItems($query)
$item = $items[0]
$webLastModifier = $web.AllUsers.GetById([int32]$item["Editor"].split(";#")[0]).DisplayName
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.  Stating that it is improved and tested is fine, but an explanation of how it is improved would be better suited.